# Função count - Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Possuo as seguintes tabelas:

```
times
- time_id INT
- time_nome VARCHAR

rodadas
- rod_id INT
- rod_rodada INT 
- rod_pontos DECIMAL (10,2)
- rod_fk_time INT
```

Preciso somar a pontuação e agrupar por time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na realidade para somar a pontuação você precisa da função `SUM`, e não da função `COUNT`. O resultado seria algo como o seguinte:

```
SELECT tim.time_nome,
       SUM(rod.rod_pontos) AS total
  FROM times tim
       INNER JOIN rodadas rod ON rod.rod_fk_time = tim.time_id
 GROUP BY tim.time_nome
 ORDER BY 2 DESC,
       tim.time_nome
```

Na query acima a função `SUM` irá somar todos os valores, separando-os pelo que está determinado na cláusula agrupadora `GROUP BY`. Sendo assim, todos os pontos de rodadas separados por `time_nome` serão somados e apresentados. Na cláusula `ORDER BY` coloquei a número `2`, indicando que a segunda coluna da `query` será utilizada em ordem decrescente (No caso o total da pontuação).